# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '_'

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am using the cort, a coreference resolution toolkit. I have installed cort using :

```
pip install cort
```

with python version 2.7

However, while running the command as mentioned in the documentation:

```
kenden@kenden-Lenovo-G500:~/deeshacodes$ cort-predict-conll -in test.conll \
           -model model.obj \
           -out output.conll \
           -extractor cort.coreference.approaches.mention_ranking.extract_substructures \
           -perceptron cort.coreference.approaches.mention_ranking.RankingPerceptron \
           -clusterer cort.coreference.clusterer.all_ante \
```

I get the folowing error:

```
 File "/home/kenden/deeshacodes/deeshaenv/bin/cort-predict-conll", line 185, in <module>
    codecs.open(args.input_filename, "r", "utf-8"))
  File "/home/kenden/deeshacodes/deeshaenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cort/core/corpora.py", line 79, in from_file
    document_as_strings]))
  File "/home/kenden/deeshacodes/deeshaenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cort/core/corpora.py", line 14, in from_string
    return documents.CoNLLDocument(string)
  File "/home/kenden/deeshacodes/deeshaenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cort/core/documents.py", line 380, in __init__
    in_sentence_ids = [int(i) for i in self.__extract_from_column(2)]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '_'
```

How can I solve this error in the packages?

Here is a link to github repo [cort](https://github.com/smartschat/cort)

This my conll file format:
test.conll

```
1       Scores        _       NNS     NNS     _       4       nsubj        _       _
2       of            _       IN      IN      _       0       erased       _       _
3       properties    _       NNS     NNS     _       1       prep_of      _       _
4       are           _       VBP     VBP     _       0       root         _       _
5       under         _       IN      IN      _       0       erased       _       _
6       extreme       _       JJ      JJ      _       8       amod         _       _
7       fire          _       NN      NN      _       8       nn           _       _
8       threat        _       NN      NN      _       4       prep_under   _       _
9       as            _       IN      IN      _      13       mark         _       _
10      a             _       DT      DT      _      12       det          _       _
11      huge          _       JJ      JJ      _      12       amod         _       _
12      blaze         _       NN      NN      _      15       xsubj        _       _
13      continues     _       VBZ     VBZ     _       4       advcl        _       _
14      to            _       TO      TO      _      15       aux          _       _
15      advance       _       VB      VB      _      13       xcomp        _       _
16      through       _       IN      IN      _       0       erased       _       _
17      Sydney        _       NNP     NNP     _      20       poss         _       _
18      's            _       POS     POS     _       0       erased       _       _
19      north-western _       JJ      JJ      _      20       amod         _       _
20      suburbs       _       NNS     NNS     _      15       prep_through _       _
21      .             _       .       .       _       4       punct        _       _
```

Comment: Because `'_'` is not an integer, it's a salamander.

Comment: @wim. salamander?

Comment: @Derik, ...I'd call this an error in your input file, not an error in the code -- it's not in the format the code expects (which calls for the given column to be strictly numeric).

Comment: ...anyhow -- a place to start would be providing the smallest possible inputs that reproduce the problem.

Comment: @wim Salamander ?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have updated my question with the updated file content. If you could help me with it. The required file format is .conll

Comment: Do you have a specification for the conll format you can point me to, so I can figure out who's right (of the software expecting column 2 to contain numbers, and the input where column 2 contains underscores)?

Comment: (Hmm; it's not helpful that "CONLL" appears to refer to a different file format for different years).

Comment: As per the github repo, conll 2012 format is used. Referring this [link](http://conll.cemantix.org/2012/data.html), I got to know that my file format is different from conll 2012 format. Is there any way to convert to conll 2012 format? @CharlesDuffy

Comment: Not sure. That might be a worthwhile question (or it might not be -- if it's effectively a tool recommendation request, those are explicitly outside site rules), but it should certainly be a *separate* question; it's outside the scope of this one.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot @CharlesDuffy